# finishing cin stream after getting values by istream_iterator

Tags: c++, vector, cin, istream-iterator

I have a simple question concerning iterator , in the following code I used three ways to get values from the pointer of iterator and put them into standard output or into vector , but the cin stream is continuous even after pressing enter key. what should be the bug in this code.... Thanks in advance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    vector<double> My_container ;

    cout << "Enter values separated by spaces : " ;


#define code1

#ifdef code1

    copy (istream_iterator<double>(cin),
          istream_iterator<double>(),
          ostream_iterator<double>(cout)) ;    

#endif // code


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#ifdef code2

    istream_iterator<double> eos ;
    istream_iterator<double> basic_input (cin);    

    while (basic_input != eos)
    {
        My_container.push_back(*basic_input) ;
        ++basic_input ;    
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < My_container.size() ; i++)
    {
        cout << i << " :" << My_container.at(i) << endl ;
    }

#endif //code2


//////////////////////////////////////////////
#ifdef code3

    istream_iterator<double> stream_end ;
    istream_iterator<double> basic_input (cin);    

    for ( ; basic_input != stream_end; ++basic_input )
    {
        My_container.push_back(*basic_input) ;
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < My_container.size() ; i++)
    {
        cout << i << " :" << My_container.at(i) << endl ;
    }

#endif //code3

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are waiting for eof in order to close the stream. Pressing enter won't do, it simply puts a newline character in the stream.

You will either have to check for a newline, or signal eof yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Your code isn't wrong per se.

**You're getting that behavior simply by design.** Why? Because `cin` skips over whitespace by default.

As @Veritas has noted you have to signal an EOF. To do so:

- On Windows: Ctrl-D (Actually type that - that's not a keyboard combination)
- On *nix: Ctrl-D (The actual keyboard combination. Technically, this is actually an [EOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-transmission_character))

Why do you have to do this? Since `cin` skips over whitespace by default, how does it know when to stop reading data? **The only way is to signal or input an EOF character (as described above) into the data stream.**

Comment: Ctrl-D isn't really eof in unix systems though. It basically flushes the input buffer making it instantly available to the iterators. So if he presses ctrl-D he should see some output but he will still be in input mode. After the buffer is flushed, pressing ctrl-D again will send 0 bytes indicating eof.